# Read all *.html files and add them to dropdown list as clickable (https) - PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working on a code that allows to read all the files in a directory with the HTML extension. These files are placed in a drop-down list. At that moment I have a piece of code that make it but I need a a little bit more.

There is the code:

```
<?php 
$files = glob("archive/*.{html}", GLOB_BRACE);
echo '<select name="file">';
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        echo '<option>' . basename($file) . '</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
?>
```

I need the names in the list not to have the HTML extension and after click on it the HTML is open in the same tab. How to add full URL with ending as the name of HTML file:
"site.com/archive/" + "example.html" to open this file after click on it? And after reload the page to have the choosen option as shown on the list?

I am newbie in PHP and I struggle with it all the time.

Thank you in advance for any advices.

Comment: To open the file after you click on it, it would make more sense to use JavaScript than PHP

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass each path as the `<option>`'s attribute `value` (example: `/archive/lorem-ipsum.html`). Note that it's the relative path to the vhost root, not necessarily to your PHP script.
2. Create a javascript event listener that listens on change of the `<select>` selected value.
3. Within the JS event listener, add a redirect (in this case I used `location.href`) to the desired value.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="file">
            <option></option>
            <?php
                $files = glob("archive/*.{html}", GLOB_BRACE);
                foreach($files as $file)
                {
                    echo '<option value="/' . $file . '">' . basename($file) . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('select[name=file]').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                location.href = event.target.value;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. I have only one issue. If the path to the x directory is: "site.com/a/b/c/archive/" than what should I do to include this path? Now the result is "site.com/archive/example.html"?

Comment: @user3770989 If the path `/a/b/c/archive/` is the same for all files in the loop, you can set the option `value` attribute to `value="/a/b/c/' . $file . '"`

Comment: Great! Thank you again for your support. A lot of learning ahead of me but it's worth it.